# Why does nothing work in my Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot with Matlab. In particular, I try with numerous online source but none of them work.

Here is my problem, I am trying to plot the expression: y=2*(x-1)/(x-4)*K*b/L, and I am interested in the range of x between 0 and 1.

```
    K=40;
    b=20;
    L=0.5;
    x=linspace(0,1,1000);
    y=2*(x-1)/(x-4)*K*b/L;
```

but it returns:

```
    y=275.01
```

I know `linspace` isn't the proper way to plot. How can I plot this function? I want to keep the K,b,L declaration because I might change them latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y=2*(x-1)./(x-4)*K*b/L;` you should use `./` replace `/`

Answer (score 1):

Like hzy199411 said, you should use the "." operation.

I would suggest that you type "help ." at a MATLAB command prompt. MATLAB will respond with a  large index of results but look for the section on "Arithmetic Operators".

You may also try the command "doc arith" but I think the "help ." is more helpful because at least in MATLAB 2013 it verbosely lists more "dot" operators.

In short several arithmetic operators prefixed with '.' ("Dot") are "Element-by-Element" operations and as such they operate on each index of the array/matrix.

For example if you had an array s=1:20 and you performed the operation s/s you would get ans = 1, where as if you did s./s you would get an array of 1's with the same length as 's'.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are a new matlab user :). The program is in general ok, but you should think of some things. First,

`linspace` is not a plotting function. The function is useful though. With your syntax it creates a vector of length 1000 with range [0,1]. For plotting, type:

```
plot(x,y);
```

Linecolor and style can be set as

```
plot(x,y,'r-.');
```

For predefined colors (here `'r-.'` means a red dotted line). There are also some additional properties that can be found be checking the online help of plot.

Also as the others say, if you want to operate on each element in the vector, use `./`. The `/` is a matrix operator.

Comment: Please help, how shall I re-formulate the code if I need to frequently change the value of the variable, without wanting to change the equation

Comment: I don't want to use linspace

Comment: Ok, what is wrong with linspace? If you want the vector to have a spcific number of elements use linspace as you do. Otherwise, if you want a spcific sampling density use something like `x = 0:0.001:1` or so. In both cases the range is defined by `0` and `1`. There can be no simpler way to do it. The minimum number of places you need to do changes in is 1 place. Or do you want me to write an example?